# How do we process get request in spring3 mvc?

Tags: javascript, spring

in client, the javascript code:

```
<script src="api/api.js?v=1.x&key=abjas23456asg" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

when browser meet this line, I guess it will send get request to the server and get the content in api.js.

but I want to process this get request, and do some other trim on content according to parameters which are v and key.

for example:

when the key is not valid, we just return a alert string but not a real api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order to do this you will need to first configure your web.xml which redirects request of .js to spring instead of directly serving.

then you will need to write Request Handler using HandlerInterceptorAdapter to intercept request and verify key parameter. if it is not available then just push alert code and dont allow further request chain to be processed by sending flase as result of preHandle.

and you can map static resources using

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/api/**" location="/api-folder/"/>
```

To configure web.xml for all resources you can set

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

For HandlerInterceptor

```
@Component
public class MyHandler extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
@Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
    throws Exception {
    String key=request.getParameter("key");
            if(invalid) {
              write alert to response 
              return false;
            }else{
                // let spring serve your static content
            } 
}

}
```

for web context xml

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="MyHandler " />
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Comment: Oh, that's it. Can you explain more details? for example: how to config web.xml to redirect js to spring and how to writeHandlerInterceptorAdapter? If you have a simple example, I'd appreciate it. Thank you very much.

Comment: add exmaple for web.xml and HandlerInterceptor

Comment: Oh, Thanks. But how to config the myHandler in xml, Is it called per request?

Comment: But I'm confused that the configuration has no mapping url. is that means that it matches all request?\

Comment: you can do mapping in web.xml for selective resources. refer to web.xml configurations.